# According to input field value echo image?

Tags: javascript

Have the following codes

```
function SetImageProperties(control)
{
    // Populate hidden fields with properties of the control
    document.getElementById("ImageName").value   = control.name;
    document.getElementById("ImageSource").value = control.src;
}


 <form>
 <div id="dhtmlgoodies_slideshow">
    <div id="galleryContainer">
    <div id="arrow_left"><img src="images/arrow_left.gif"></div>
    <div id="arrow_right"><img src="images/arrow_right.gif"></div>
    <div id="theImages">
        <img src="http://www.fastflowers.com.au/Skin/FastFlowers/Images/Products/210,210/Australiana.jpg" name="image1.jpg" onclick="SetImageProperties(this)"/></a>
        <div id="slideEnd"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div><input type="text" value="" id="ImageName" name="ImageName"/>
<input type="text" value="" id="ImageSource" name="ImageSource"/></form>
```

Getting the image src and image name into the input field. In "ImageSource" getting the src of image. Again How I display the image using the "ImageSource"? Means according to input field want to echo the image again.

Comment: Why is this question tagged "php"? You want to show image by Javascript or by inserting `img src=...` from php in some new page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new `<div id="selectedImage">` that stores the result. Then create an `<img>` element according to the inputs and append the results.

```javascript
function SetImageProperties(control)
{
    // Populate hidden fields with properties of the control
    document.getElementById("ImageName").value   = control.name;
    document.getElementById("ImageSource").value = control.src;
    // Create new image
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = control.src;
    img.setAttribute("name", control.name);
    // Output results
    var target = document.getElementById("selectedImage");
    target.innerHTML = "You selected the image:<br/>";
    target.appendChild(img);
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R6zs6/4/).

Comment: Antony... If somebody select the image, want to display the image again in same page.

Comment: @SudhaSarath You mean duplicating the image?

Comment: Not duplicating. Display again the selected image. Select the image, get the image name and src into input fields, again display the selected image.

Comment: @SudhaSarath I'm sorry, but this is very confusing. Why display the image again and again?

Comment: ok...let me explain again. Somebody select an image. I want to display like "you selected image is" --- display the image what he selected.